# How to fix Python request pagination that stop working

Tags: python, python-requests

I use this code below to make a python request. I want to get all products result for query "v".

```
url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/1003-York-pa/search?query=ice%20cream'
api_url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/electrode/api/search'

params = {
    'query': 'v',
    'cat_id': 0,
    'ps': 24,
    'offset': 0,
    'prg': 'desktop',
    'stores': re.search(r'store/(\d+)', url).group(1)
}

data1 = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()


for page in range(0, 319):

        params = {
            'query': word,
            'cat_id': 0,
            'page':page,     // try to update the new page
            'ps': 24,
            'offset': 0,
            'prg': 'desktop',
            'stores': re.search(r'store/(\d+)', url).group(1)
        }

 data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
```

the website search shows 319 pages of result. it some stop returning results at page 100. I want to get the result for all the pages. How can I do this?

Comment: I assume you mean that the search returns 319 pages when you do it in your browser.  If so, maybe there's something different about your query in code than what you do in your browser such that the result only has 100 pages.  It could also be that Walmart is limiting the number of pages it returns when it recognizes that an automated web client (a script) is making the requests.

Comment: your request is happening outside the loop, hence only the last value of page is used in the request. Essentially all the previous params with pages *1-318* are overwritten and when the request is sent only page parameter *319* is sent. Indent `data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()` and you should be good to go. Also it might be better to make changes to the offset parameter as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to increment `offset` parameter, not `page`:

```
import re
import requests


url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/1003-York-pa/search?query=ice%20cream'
api_url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/electrode/api/search'

params = {
    'query': 'ice cream',
    'cat_id': 0,
    'ps': 24,
    'offset': 0,
    'prg': 'desktop',
    'stores': re.search(r'store/(\d+)', url).group(1)
}

count = 0

for params['offset'] in range(0, 319, 24):

    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

    for i in data.get('items', []):
        print(i['title'])
        count += 1

print('Total', count)
```

Prints:

```
...

Paletas Helados Mexico Rompope Premium Bolis, 5.0 fl oz, 6 count
Blue Ribbon Classics Homemade Vanilla Frozen Treat Bar
Dean's Country Fresh Fudge Bars, 30 oz
Blue Ribbon Classics Star Frozen Treat Bar
Dean Foods Deans Country Fresh  Vanilla Bars, 12 ea
Blue Ribbon Classics Orange Dream Frozen Treat Bar
OUTSHINE Creamy Coconut Frozen Fruit Bars, 6 Ct. Box | Gluten Free
La Michoacana Variety Pack Paletas, 12 ct, 36 fl oz
Breyers CarbSmart Frozen Dairy Dessert Vanilla Bars 6 ct
Total 484
```

Comment: I think what you did should work but I'm not able to retrieve all the result for single letter queries like querying for letter  A, B